# Nvidia drivers suddenly not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

Today I started up my laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 and suddenly I can't go through the login page, as soon as I insert the credentials the screen freezes, the mouse pointer is stuck and I can't do a thing. I searched a little and, after trying some stuff I found in this forum, I think the problem is the Nvidia drivers (I have a 1050Ti Mobile): as soon as I do the  `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` I can login, but I can't use the system at all, it freezes after a while. In the case I can login, if I look at the additional drivers the graphic card is using the Nuveau one, and if I try to set another one it gets stuck.
 I tried the `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` but it didn't work, I tried to do the `nomodeset` thing and install the drivers with "Additional drivers" tool but it gets stuck again, I tried to remove the *ppa repository* and add it again to get the recommended driver (it gives me the 430 driver as recommended) and then install it but nothing. What could it be? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting into a Wayland session instead of Xorg ? I had exactly the same  problem as you but with  nvidia-430 installed. I had a black screen  and frozen mouse when using Xorg, and Wayland worked normally.

If you load a session successfully, whats happens when you run   `sudo nvidia-settings` ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/958969)

Comment: so even if i might have some useful info because i had the same problem , i can neither  comment nor  answer ?  what a wonderful site

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts. The limit to comment on someone else's post is because a lot of people thing this is a forum, whereas it's not.  If you can answer without asking for additional info, please answer, but don't use the answer section to ask for more info: you will get that part of the reputation soon enough (50 rep and above so you can get the hang of how the site works)  **0:-)** @abu